Document Library doesn't mirror column across users
I created this document library with a dropdown section for “Sub Policy” and an “Authorised By” field.  Whilst logged in as admin I updated the "sub policy" details and "authorised by". I hadn’t tested it on a user at this point as I assumed the details from both fields would be inherited/propagate to all users, no matter who was logged on.  I setup a few permissions on some of the documents only allowing management to access them and then went to test with a standard user.  When I logged on, all the "Sub Policy" and "Authorised by" details were missing.  The standard user only has view access.  I have attached screen shots from both logins (SA is admin and A is the end user).  All and any help/advice is very much appreciated.



Did you publish the documents? Editors can view draft documents with edited properties, whereas readers can only view published version of the documents.
